# How to select the elements by `tabindex`

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like create a array by selecting the elements by `tabindex` is it possible?
if so what is the correct way to do? I understood that, we need to loop through all element and find the prop declared with `tabindex` but looking for the right way.

```
<div class="focusguard" id="focusguard-1" tabindex="0"></div>
<div>
  <input class="user-input" type="text" autofocus tabindex="1">
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="first-item" tabindex="2">
      <span>Item 1</span>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="3">Item 2</li>
    <li tabindex="4">Item 3</li>
    <li tabindex="5">Item 4</li>
    <li tabindex="6">Item 5</li>
    <li tabindex="7">Item 6</li>
    <li tabindex="8">Item 7</li>
    <li tabindex="9">Item 8</li>
    <li tabindex="10">Item 9</li>
    <li class="last-item" tabindex="11">Item 10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can i create a new array  by `tabindex` -?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('[tabindex])` ?

Comment: @cloned was faster: `const test3 = document.querySelector("[tabindex='3']");
console.info(test.innerText);` will get the text for the `tabindex="3"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all elements with a tabindex on it:

```
const elmntsWithTabindex = document.querySelectorAll('[tabindex]')
```

This will give you a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which is not actually an array but can be converted to an array if needed:

```
const arrayOfElmnts = Array.from(elmntsWithTabindex)
```

You may, however, not need to convert it to an array because NodeLists already come with some useful methods like [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach):

```
elmntsWithTabindex.forEach( elmnt => {
  // Do something with that one element
})
```